# How to install email system on Debian 6.0

Tags: email, debian

As title says i wanna full email support on my Debian 6.0 VPS.

1. It can send/Receive emails thround roudcube or something
2. I cann add more email accounts to my domain

I used Google and didn't find nothing that worked. I tried about five different tutorials and none worked.

Please help. All maills set to my mail comes to dead.letter file in my www root directory.

I have Apache, PHP5, SQL servers installed + Webmin CP. I host my website on that.

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Did you check your log files to see why it isn't working?

Comment: Which log files? Where are these files located?

Comment: That depends on which mail server you are using. Is it postfix/dovecot/exim? Should be in /var/log/

Comment: I do not have any of these email servers. I have debian 6 32-bit with LAMP and sendmail server. I don't known how to configure any of these email servers you mentioned. I have no experience with that. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) Switch sendmail to postfix.**

Default `sendmail` config is for local delivery only. That means `mail root`, `mail local-username` will work. Sending anything with a domain name will not work. It will NOT send to external email address. It will NOT receive any email from external.

`sendmail` is a solid email server package. However, due to its cryptic configuration format, less people are using/learning it. `postfix`, `courier` or `exim` are the norm now.

**(2) Install Dovecot**

`postfix` is for sending and receiving email. To pick up email remotely with pop3/imap4, you need `dovecot` or `courier`.

**(3) Advice for Webmin**

DO NOT MIX WEBMIN WITH MANUAL CONFIGURATION. <-- Repeat that 3 times!!

`Webmin` save all your settings in its own database, then write them to configuration files of different packages(eg. postfix, dovecot, etc). Every time you make a change with `webmain` and hit save/apply, it rewrite the configuration file.

For example, look at the following sequence

1. use `webmin` to config `postfix`
2. edit `postfix` configuration file by hand
3. use `webmin` to change `postfix` settings

All changes in step 2 are lost.

If you are going to use webmin, configure everything with webmin, do the webmin way. No mixing!

Comment: Which is just one reason why you shouldn't use webmin.

Comment: Thatnks. Thats really helps. Okay i installed everything from begining. Now how to use webmin to configure my server to have roundcube to send and recive emails? My domain mail.domain.com is already pointing to my server.

Comment: Install roundcube from command line. then configure from webmin. roundcube maybe a little tricky to configure. Post here or another question if you get stuck.

Comment: I configured my roundcube and now it says: Connection failed: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused)
Something wrong with SMTP an IMAP


When i configured it in roundcube i didn't typed username and password because i don't known.

EDIT:

Comment: Open a new question, then post a comment here, I will post comment over there, otherwise there will be too many comment here and we will be kick off this post. Happen to me before already, lol.

Comment: Here: http://serverfault.com/questions/461038/troubles-installing-email-system-on-debian-6-0

I explained more in question