# Troubles with Dovecot + Webmin on Debian 6.0

Tags: email, debian

I installed Apache, PHP5, MySQL and Webmin on a vps. I host my website on that.

I completely reinstalled whole VPS with fresh installation of Postfix and Dovecot. But Dovecot fails to start, so Roundcube can't connect.

I installed Postfix, Apache, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, Dovecot using this source: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-squeeze-with-bind-and-dovecot-ispconfig

Need some guidance to bring Dovecot up.

Comment: (1) Do you know your mysql root password? (2) Post `grep -i dovecot /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Yes i know it. 
But if i properly understand this log, im not allowed to use root account for loggingin in dovecot. IM going to try with another account.

Log is here:
http://pastebin.com/JvaqJZM6

Comment: Postfix is also down. 

Dec 27 04:33:31 server4 postfix/master[719]: fatal: bind 0.0.0.0 port 25: Address already in use
Dec 27 04:33:36 server4 postfix/postqueue[822]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly


2 - I tried with new created user account to login on roundcube but it says authentication failed.

Dovecot:
Dec 27 04:36:56 server4 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (tried to use unsupported auth mechanism): method=PLAIN, rip=94.249.208.215, lip=94.249.208.215, secured

Comment: Post output of "pstree ". You may have exim4 running. "apt-get purge exim4"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ueRvjHtP

Comment: Sendmail still running,  purge that.

Comment: Package exim4 is not installed, so not removed - Result of apt-get purge exim4

Comment: Postfix works now but it use Dec 27 05:36:49 server4 postfix/local[17683]: 60D942034E3: to=<root@mail.elite7h                                                              ackers.us>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=477, delays=469/0.12/0/8.1, dsn=2                                                              .0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")

But it use 
root@mail.elite7hackers.us i want email staff@elite7hackers.us

Comment: I figured out everything and all works now. It sends/receives emails. One more question:
Why my sender address is test@mail.domain.com? I wanna it to be test@domain.com ...
As i can see this is problem with roundcube. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use roundcube and shown as test@domain.com, you should login roundcube with your full email address `test@domain.com`. If you forget to do so, it will append the full machine name.

### Update

In roundcube config, setup the following

```
$rcmail_config['username_domain'] = '<the-domain-name>';
```

Go through your webmin interface and learn how to put it in. There is webmin module for roundcube.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. 
Dec 28 09:01:41 server4 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts): user=<example@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=XX.XXX.XXX.215, lip=XX.XXX.XXX.215, secured

Comment: Updated answer. If it is configure correctly, login roundcube without the domain portion.